# Installing Updates selectively from command line

Tags: upgrade, security

I have gone through forums and could not find a definitive answer for a requirement that I have. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have a server machine running Ubuntu 11.10 server. When I log in to it I see a message of the form

60 packages can be updated.
23 updates are security updates.

How can I install updates selectively(pick and choose) through command line.  For instance I might want to install only the security updates. I know that support for 11.10 has ended. But I cannot upgrade to a higher version at the moment.

As I mentioned earlier, I'm on 11.10 and cannot upgrade to a later version. I'm not sure if I run apt-get dist-upgrade, will it upgrade me from 11.10 to some higher version, or will I stay on 11.10 and only updates for 11.10 will be installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get only security updates, follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/121642/147044), but insert only next line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse
```